# Remove every third element from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

In this code piece I print the index numbers in a list.

```
x = '1 2 3 4 67 8'
x = list(map(int, x.split()))
# something here with modulo??
print(x)
```

Output:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 67, 8]

I want to output 
[1, 2, 4, 67]

So the 3th element, 6th, 9th etc...

Comment: you need to iterate over the list, get the index, and when the index modulo 3 (%) operator equals zero, then you need to delete item
`index%3 ==0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate the list and keep index value which is not multiple of 3

```
[value for key,value in enumerate(x,1) if key%3!=0 ]
```